# Is there a tool other than ij to look into a local derby database (folder)?

Tags: java, database, derby, viewer

I'm using Derby ij to look into my local Apache Derby database. It's just a folder and I connect to it like this:

```
 connect 'jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Torben\MyDatabase' USER 'me' PASSWORD 'secret';
```

It works, but I don't really like to look into the database in the console. Is there another tool for this? The best would be something with a GUI.

Comment: Here is a list of applications: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby#Products_By_Type

Comment: DBVisualizer is another tool, you can connect to many DBs

Comment: Above link (wiki.apache.org/....) is no more valid. New link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DERBY/UsesOfDerby (but needs an apache-login)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) can connect to an Apache Derby database.
[Getting Started using the SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/paper/GettingStartedusingtheSQuirreLSQLClient.pdf)

Comment: RazorSQl is another option (more user friendly than squirrel in my opinion), but it is free just for 30 days =(

Answer (score 6):

I use DBeaver Community Edition (free and open source).

When comparing DBeaver CE 6.0.2 (2019-04-08) against SQuirreL 3.9.1 (2019-02-24) I noticed that SQuirreL does not show some database objects (eg. sequences).

DBeaver supports intellisense / auto-completion, updating table rows in-place (ie. "select for update"), and can globally apply filters on schemas and catalogs in connection settings (eg. exclude SYS schemas from the object tree display). It can also run pre- and post-connection scripts (handy for initialising an ij session with preferences eg. protocols).

[image]

Comment: Worked great - intuitive and super easy to set up.  Automatically downloaded the Derby driver files for me.

Answer (score 2):

I simply use NetBeans IDE (Services -> Databases) to connect to my local or remote derby databases.

You can also create new derby databases there.