# use derby ij against an existing database

Tags: database, ubuntu, command-line-interface, derby

While I'm having [some trouble installing and setting up derby](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179634/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-derby-tools-ij), I do have partial success:

```
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# ll
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Aug 23 16:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5  501 staff 4096 Aug 23 02:07 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4 Aug 23 02:07 dbex.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    38 Aug 23 02:07 db.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   187 Aug 23 16:46 derby.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 23 02:07 log/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 23 02:07 seg0/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   868 Aug 23 02:07 service.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 23 02:07 tmp/
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
ij version 10.9
ij> quit;
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby#
```

How do I now query this particular database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full example, using Derby and Squirrel, presuming you have a Derby database already installed on the system:

1. Install [Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/#installation) into `$HOME/bin/squirrel`
2. Install [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) into `$HOME/bin/db-derby`
3. Run Squirrel (`cd $HOME/bin/squirrel ; ./squirrel-sql.sh`)
4. Click **Drivers** to open the Drivers panel.
5. Double-click **Apache Derby Embedded**.
6. Click **Extra Class Path**.
7. Click **Add**.
8. Choose `$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar`.
9. Set **Example URL** to the database path (e.g., the directory containing `seg0`).
10. Click **OK** to save.

At this point the Apache Derby Embedded icon should no longer have a red X.

Then:

1. Click the **Aliases** tab.
2. Set **Name** to: DerbyDB
3. Ensure **Driver** is set to: Apache Derby Embedded
4. Verify the **URL** is pointing to the directory containing `seg0`.
5. Click **OK** (no username or password needed?).
6. Click **Connect**.

The database is now connected and you should see the schemas.

Then:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+n</kbd> to display a new SQL editor window, or click the **SQL** tab.
2. Type: `SELECT * FROM SYS.SYSTABLES`
3. Click the Running human icon (or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>) to execute the query.

You can now execute SQL statements against the Derby database.

Note: This does not technically answer the question, as this answer does not explain how to use the interactive command-line interface (`ij`). The answer proposes a viable alternative to querying the database using Squirrel's graphical interface.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how to really query the db itself, but it's fairly simple to connect, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424892/is-there-a-tool-other-than-ij-to-look-into-a-local-derby-database-folder?rq=1):

```
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# pwd
/root/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Aug 23 18:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5  501 staff 4096 Aug 23 02:07 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1092 Aug 23 18:24 derby.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 23 02:07 log/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 23 02:07 seg0/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   868 Aug 23 02:07 service.properties
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# 
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby# java org.apache.derby.tools.ij 
ij version 10.9
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:/root/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby';
ij> 
;
ij> show schema;
ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "show" at line 1, column 1.
Issue the 'help' command for general information on IJ command syntax.
Any unrecognized commands are treated as potential SQL commands and executed directly.
Consult your DBMS server reference documentation for details of the SQL syntax supported by your server.
ij> 
;
ij> show schemas;
TABLE_SCHEM                   
------------------------------
APP                           
NULLID                        
SQLJ                          
SYS                           
SYSCAT                        
SYSCS_DIAG                    
SYSCS_UTIL                    
SYSFUN                        
SYSIBM                        
SYSPROC                       
SYSSTAT                       

11 rows selected
ij> show tables;
TABLE_SCHEM         |TABLE_NAME                    |REMARKS             
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS                 |SYSALIASES                    |                    
SYS                 |SYSCHECKS                     |                    
SYS                 |SYSCOLPERMS                   |                    
SYS                 |SYSCOLUMNS                    |                    
SYS                 |SYSCONGLOMERATES              |                    
SYS                 |SYSCONSTRAINTS                |                    
SYS                 |SYSDEPENDS                    |                    
SYS                 |SYSFILES                      |                    
SYS                 |SYSFOREIGNKEYS                |                    
SYS                 |SYSKEYS                       |                    
SYS                 |SYSPERMS                      |                    
SYS                 |SYSROLES                      |                    
SYS                 |SYSROUTINEPERMS               |                    
SYS                 |SYSSCHEMAS                    |                    
SYS                 |SYSSEQUENCES                  |                    
SYS                 |SYSSTATEMENTS                 |                    
SYS                 |SYSSTATISTICS                 |                    
SYS                 |SYSTABLEPERMS                 |                    
SYS                 |SYSTABLES                     |                    
SYS                 |SYSTRIGGERS                   |                    
SYS                 |SYSVIEWS                      |                    
SYSIBM              |SYSDUMMY1                     |                    
APP                 |JAMES_DOMAIN                  |                    
APP                 |JAMES_MAIL                    |                    
APP                 |JAMES_MAILBOX                 |                    
APP                 |JAMES_MAIL_PROPERTY           |                    
APP                 |JAMES_MAIL_USERFLAG           |                    
APP                 |JAMES_RECIPIENT_REWRITE       |                    
APP                 |JAMES_SUBSCRIPTION            |                    
APP                 |JAMES_USER                    |                    
APP                 |OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE        |                    

31 rows selected
ij> quit;
root@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4/var/store/derby#
```

Comment: an example query would be: select * from app.james_mailbox;