# Derby Database Desginer view

Tags: derby

Is there any tools through which we can see the designer view of the database in derby.
I want to see the the complete structure of the database like in phpmyadmin we can see using Designer View.

Comment: Perhaps something like SQL Squirrel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4425160/193453

Comment: I got the solution..DbSchema is solution for everything..thanks for  reply @BryanPendleton

Answer (score 0):

Something had asked similar question.

See
[use derby ij against an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101567/use-derby-ij-against-an-existing-database?lq=1)

if you are a user of RAD and intelliJ Idea, they provide plugins to view the data.
For IBM RAD, use the perspective Database Explorer.