# Watch the created tables and entries

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipselink, derby

I follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html and I and did section 4 ,I run the main program and I saw in console that the entries created,my qustion is how can I see the table that created and the entries inside of it ,where can I find it ?

Comment: You can find your table in the database. No? If you use H2 or HSQLDB - you may open DB file an see them there.

Comment: I think derby should generate DB file also. However I'm usure, never used Derby

Comment: Correct but I didnt find the tables entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that Derby stores its data not in plain text but in something other. Can't help this way. You should look for the way to connect to Derby database with some Viewer application and open that table. Read this thread: [Is there a tool other than ij to look into a local derby database (folder)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424892/is-there-a-tool-other-than-ij-to-look-into-a-local-derby-database-folder)

Comment: Thanks I download it ,I have the jar file of the derby so how should I configure it since it ask for URL and I dont know if I have one and how to provide it...any idea?

Comment: I think it ask for file URL