# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'ADMIN' does not exist

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, derby

I'm trying to use DerbyDB in an Eclipse Project.

The situation in my workspace directory is

[image: dir situation]

DerbyDB.java is implemented as follow

```
package database;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import shoppingCart.Product;
import graphicUnitInterface.User;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

public class DerbyDB {
    private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:DerbyDB;create=True";
    private static String SQL_STATEMENT;
    private static final DerbyDB Singleton = new DerbyDB();

    private DerbyDB(){}

    public static DerbyDB getInstance() {       
        return Singleton;
    }

    public void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException{ 
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection connect;
        
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
            DatabaseMetaData data = connect.getMetaData();
            ResultSet res = data.getTables(null, null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
            
            if(!res.next()) {

                connect.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA (idCat INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, descr VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)");
                connect.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO CATEGORIA (nome, descr) VALUES " +
                                                    "('Smartphone', 'Smartphone di ultima generazione')," +
                                                    "('Action Camera', 'Registra tutto cio che vuoi')," +
                                                    "('Laptop', 'Porta con te tutti i tuoi file ed i tuoi programmi')," +
                                                    "('Monitor', 'Acquista solo il meglio per il tuo computer fisso')");
                System.out.println("CATEGORIA table created and populated");

                
                connect.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE PRODOTTO (idProd INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, descr VARCHAR(45), stock INTEGER NOT NULL, prezzo FLOAT NOT NULL, idCat INTEGER NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT idCat FOREIGN KEY (idCat) REFERENCES CATEGORIA)");
                connect.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO PRODOTTO (nome, descr, stock, prezzo, idCat) VALUES " +
                                                    "('Samsung S7', 'Smartphone di moda della casa Samsung', 13, 649.90, 1)," +
                                                    "('HTC 10', 'Ultima uscita in casa HTC', 5, 699.90, 1)," +
                                                    "('Xiaomi Yi Camera', 'Action Camera di Xiaomi', 21, 71.90, 2)," +
                                                    "('DELL XPS 13', 'Silent Laptop con grandezza dello schermo pari a 13 pollici', 7, 1149.00, 3)," +
                                                    "('Asus ROG G752', 'Laptop da Gaming: gaming without limits', 8, 1362.59, 3)," +
                                                    "('Dell Ultrasharp U2515H', 'Monitor IPS dal grande rendimento, 25 pollici', 15, 324.99, 4)," +
                                                    "('Asus ROG SWIFT PG278Q', 'Monitor 27 pollici da gaming', 2, 657.79, 4)," +
                                                    "('LG G5', 'Il nuovo LG G5 supera tutti i limiti', 11, 410.00, 1)");
                System.out.println("PRODOTTO table created and populated");
                

                connect.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (nick VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, pw VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, cognome VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, via VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, citta VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, cap CHAR(5) NOT NULL, tel VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL)");
                connect.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO CLIENTE VALUES " +
                                                    "('cristyB', 'canecasa', 'cristinabuonomo@gmail.com', 'Cristina', 'Buonomo', 'Via Europa 55', 'Pollena Trocchia', '80040', '0816953652')," +
                                                    "('theOne', 'pass1234', 'antonioesposito@gmail.com', 'Antonio', 'Esposito', 'Via Toledo 33', 'Napoli', '80134', '0815693256')," +
                                                    "('Maradona10', 'grandenapoli', 'gennysavastano@gmail.com', 'Genny', 'Savastano', 'Via Broggia 15', 'Napoli', '80135' '0815694563')," +
                                                    "('C1r0', 'baubau', 'ciromantovani@gmail.com', 'Ciro', 'Mantovani', 'Corso Umberto I 144', 'Napoli', '80138', '0815698878')");
                System.out.println("CLIENTE table created and populated");
                
                
                connect.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE ADMIN (nick VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, pw VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL)");
                connect.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO ADMIN VALUES " +
                                                    "('admin', 'root', 'federicocuozzo@gmail.com')," +
                                                    "('admin2', 'toor', 'admin2@gmail.com')");
                System.out.println("ADMIN table created and populated");
                                            
                
                connect.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE ACQUISTA (dataAcquisto DATE NOT NULL, oraAcquisto TIME NOT NULL, nick VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, idProd INTEGER NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT nick FOREIGN KEY (nick) REFERENCES CLIENTE, CONSTRAINT idProd FOREIGN KEY (idProd) REFERENCES PRODOTTO, PRIMARY KEY (dataAcquisto, oraAcquisto))");
                System.out.println("ACQUISTA table created");
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();      
        }
    }
```

... but, when I want to run Main.java and I want to login to the reserved area, I've the error in the title: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'ADMIN' does not exist.

The query connected to the event "button pressed" is

```
public User checkAdmin(String nick, String pw) throws SQLException {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        Statement stat = connect.createStatement();
        User user = null;
        
        SQL_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM ADMIN WHERE ADMIN.nick = '"+ nick +"' AND ADMIN.pw ='"+ pw +"'";
        
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(SQL_STATEMENT);
        
        if(res.next())
            user = new User(res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), null, null, null, null, null, null);
            
        if(stat != null) 
            stat.close();
        if(connect != null) 
            connect.close();
        
        return user;
    }
```

What's the problem? How can I resolve it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you check whether table `ADMIN` exists in DB ? Your query is `SELECT * FROM ADMIN` and you are getting `ADMIN` doe not exists.

Comment: How can I check that table `admin` exists? Where have I to go to check it?

Comment: Please refer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424892/is-there-a-tool-other-than-ij-to-look-into-a-local-derby-database-folder` to connect to Derby DB. You can also use https://razorsql.com/ .

Comment: I've used Squirrel to connect to the DerbyDB. I've checked that table admin doesn't exist in the DB. I've run my sql query into squirrel and it works, but however, values aren't inserted in the table. It seems there's a problem with DerbyDB.java and connection, but I can't understand the problem ...

Comment: I've some news ... If I create table and insert values with Squirrel, my application works, but If I try to create table with DerbyDB.java, it doesn't work :(

Comment: You're probably using two different databases. The URL `jdbc:derby:DerbyDB;create=true` specifies a relative URL to the databases 'DerbyDB', so you have probably created two different DerbyDB databases, in two different folders. Search your hard disk to find them.

Comment: There's just one DerbyDB database in my Hard Disks and infact queries work well.. just creation and population weren't work...I've resolved it using Squirrel...